# Activity for Tablet and Phone Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a phone android application that works and now I would like to develop a version for tablet. According to the research I have done, I can keep only one project for that, I "only" have to handle different screen size with multiple layouts and drawables.

However it is not clear for me, if I have for example 2 layouts for my home page (one for each device), do I have to develop 2 activities? Or can I have only one activity in which I can detect which layout is loaded and do my stuffs in if/else branch?

Please note that my layouts are very different, for example for tablet version I am using DrawerLayout to have a sidebar whereas I don't for phone version.

Comment: You don't need to develop one activity per screen support (tablet/phone), the Android Operative System automatically select the corresponding XML that fits the resolution of the device, but you must be take care with the View Binding, thats mean, that you must respect the view type of the views with the same id name in both layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I have for example 2 layouts for my home page (one for each device), do I have to develop 2 activities?

No. If you have two different versions of your layout (perhaps one in `layout/` and another in `layout-sw600dp/`), the system will automatically choose the correct one for you.

> Or can I have only one activity in which I can detect which layout is loaded and do my stuffs in if/else branch?

This is approximately what is usually done, only you often don't need to do an if/else everywhere.

You mention that your tablet layout will be using `DrawerLayout` and your phone layout will not. That means you can write code like this:

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);

if (drawer != null) {
    // set up drawer for tablets
}
```

The `findViewById()` call will successfully return your `DrawerLayout` when the system has selected the tablet layout, and it will return `null` when the system has selected your phone layout.

However, if there's a view that you know is present in **both** your phone and tablet layouts, you can just use it directly:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
textView.setText("hello world");
```